# UITableView with custom UITableViewCell not displaying properly

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, subclass

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` (actually I have subclassed it a few times for different tables) and occasionally the table will start to "degrade" and slowly crash. It is impossible to reproduce the crash and it crashes with the following call stack:

Application Specific Information:
Order Remote failed to resume in time

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 0.240 (user 0.040, system 0.200), 12% CPU
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.000, 0% CPU

```
Thread 0:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x310932b8 semaphore_wait_trap + 8  
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x310c0b46 semaphore_wait + 2  
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3116a7c4 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 296  
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31169cb4 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow + 128  
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3042bb70 __CFMachPortPerform + 92  
5   CoreFoundation                  0x304236f8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 20  
6   CoreFoundation                  0x304236bc __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 160  
7   CoreFoundation                  0x30415f76 __CFRunLoopRun + 514  
8   CoreFoundation                  0x30415c80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224  
9   CoreFoundation                  0x30415b88 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52  
10  GraphicsServices                0x31eec4a4 GSEventRunModal + 108  
11  GraphicsServices                0x31eec550 GSEventRun + 56  
12  UIKit                           0x313cf322 -[UIApplication _run] + 406  
13  UIKit                           0x313cce8c UIApplicationMain + 664  
14  Order Remote                    0x00002a02 0x1000 + 6658  
15  Order Remote                    0x000029cc 0x1000 + 6604
```

Here is what it looks like when it it about to crash...

http://img819.imageshack.us/i/uitableviewmissingdata2.jpg/

http://img220.imageshack.us/i/uitableviewmissingdata1.jpg/

I've been through all my memory management code and enabled zombies and checked how I subclass the cell and I can't see where I am going wrong. Please help me.

...

here is some code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    MenuItemCell *cell = (MenuItemCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MenuItemCell"];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[MenuItemCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MenuItemCell"] autorelease];
        DLog( @"MenuViewController::cellForRowAtIndexPath: allocating memory for a MenuItemCell" );
    }
    else
    {
        DLog( @"MenuViewController::cellForRowAtIndexPath: dequeuing an existing MenuItemCell for reuse" );
    }

    cell.accessoryType =  UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    // only display the item modifiers view if the item has one or more modifiers
    if( [[selectedCategory getModifiers] count] > 0 )
    {
        cell.accessoryType =  UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    cell.textLabel.text = [[items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] name];

    // build a mutable string from the modifiers and set the text to the result in the detail label
    NSMutableString* modifiers = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@""];
    Item* i = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    for( ItemModifier* modifier_iterator in [i modifiers] )
    {
        [modifiers appendString: [modifier_iterator name]];
        [modifiers appendString: @" "];
    }

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = modifiers;

    [modifiers release];
    modifiers = nil;

    [cell setItem: i];

    return cell;
}
```

@interface MenuItemCell : UITableViewCell 
    {
        UILabel* itemCount;
    }

```
- (void) setItem: (Item*) item;
- (void) resetItemCount;

@end

@implementation MenuItemCell

- (id) initWithStyle: (UITableViewCellStyle) style reuseIdentifier: (NSString*) reuseIdentifier
{
    if( (self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) )
    {
        itemCount = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [[self contentView] addSubview:itemCount];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void) resetItemCount
{
    [itemCount setText: @""];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void) layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    float inset = 10.0;
    CGRect bounds = [[self contentView] bounds];
    float h = bounds.size.height;
    float w = bounds.size.width;

    CGRect accessoryViewBounds;

    if( !self.accessoryView )
    {
        accessoryViewBounds = CGRectZero;
    }
    else 
    {
        accessoryViewBounds = self.accessoryView.bounds;
    }

    CGRect textLabelBounds = self.textLabel.bounds;

    CGRect innerFrame = CGRectMake( round( inset + w / 2), textLabelBounds.origin.y, round( w / 2 - accessoryViewBounds.size.width - inset * 3 ), h - 1 );

    if( ( innerFrame.size.height >= bounds.size.height ) || ( innerFrame.size.width >= bounds.size.width ) )
    {
        [NSException raise:@"inner frame for MenuItemCell is larger than the contentView bounds" format:@"MenuItemCell (w: %d h: %d) contentView (w: %d h: %d)", innerFrame.size.width, innerFrame.size.height, bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height];
    }

    // move the rectange to the right side of the cell
    itemCount.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
    itemCount.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    itemCount.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    itemCount.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:[UIFont labelFontSize]];

    [itemCount setFrame: innerFrame];
}

- (void) setItem: (Item*) item
{
    if( [item count] > 0 )
    {
        [itemCount setText: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", [item count]]];
    }
    else 
    {
        [itemCount setText: @""];
    }

    [self setNeedsDisplay];

    DLog( @"MenuItemCell::itemCount %@ %d", [item name], [item count] );
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    [itemCount release];
    itemCount = nil;

    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: Code would help here. At the very least, your -[SomeDataSource tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] and your subclass of UITableViewCell.

Comment: added the code for cellForRowAtIndexPath and the table view cell subclass for one of my classes..

Answer (score 0):

The problem was probably (I can't confirm because the behaviour was so erratic and non-reproducable) related to not releasing IBOutlet defined pointers in viewDidUnload. I didn't realise that they were retained until re-reading the docs.

I also changed all of my simple accessors to @properties rather than defining my own to reduce the risk of dodgy memory management techniques.

```
...

@interface MenuViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{
    IBOutlet UITableView* itemsTable;
    NSMutableArray* items;

    Category* selectedCategory;
    Order* editingOrder;
    NSIndexPath* selectedRow;

    BOOL addItemToExistingOrder;
}

-(id)initWithCategory: (Category*)category;
-(IBAction)addItem: (id)sender;

@property (assign) Category* selectedCategory;    
@property (assign) NSMutableArray* items;    
@property (assign) Order* editingOrder;    
@property (assign) BOOL addItemToExistingOrder;    

@implementation
- (void)viewDidUnload
{    
    [super viewDidUnload];

    [selectedRow release];
    selectedRow = nil;

    [itemsTable release];
    itemsTable = nil;
}
```